# local document link to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, filter

I have file a server with huge size (more than 50 TB).

What my manager want is to create a search on these document from SharePoint with metadata filters (not content search).

Basically what I am looking for, is that I save the metadata of each document into sharepoint list and attached the link of local document with this metadata ( document will not be uploaded into sharepoint). After that I will be able to search the document via its and other metadata filter.

When I click on document link in SharePoint it will open the document from the local file server.

I am using SharePoint Online.

Comment: Probably the easiest way will be do do it in PowerShell, (Read item, and then used SPOnline PnP to create item; please note that your approach will not keep the security of the item and you will not be able to search on the contents of the document (for that you need Hybrid Search set up)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell cmdlets to read the properties of the files of the file server, then use SharePoint Online PowerShell cmdlets to create items into a list using these properties.

There are two useful articles for your reference:
[Use a PowerShell Cmdlet to Work with File Attributes](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/26/use-a-powershell-cmdlet-to-work-with-file-attributes/)
[Sharepoint Online: Working with multiple items using Powershell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31382.sharepoint-online-working-with-multiple-items-using-powershell.aspx)